# SQL Server replace multiple backslashes

Tags: sql-server, string, replace

in SQL Server I have a column which holds the path to a pdf file like this: "\\\\path\\to\\file.pdf" and I want to replace the backslashes to get this: "\\path\to\file.pdf.

I tried to use REPLACE on the escaped backslashes, but it has not worked properly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show us the actual path data in your table.  Do you really have two/four literal backslashes there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to replace 2 backslashes with 1 backslash it works with replace:

```
SELECT REPLACE('\\\path\\to\\file.pdf', '\\', '\')
```

Returns

> \\path\to\file.pdf

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/89832/0)

Comment: It's not clear if this requirement is a one-off or if it would need to run multiple times. It's also not clear if there is always double the amount of backslashes, or whether there can be a different amount, for example, \\\\\\path\to\\\file.pdf. This is a good and valid answer, but if this were the case, then this answer would not work. Perhaps you can loop over the code multiple times to remove all backslashes to a single backslash and then add the final one back in on the left hand side using a CONCAT?